# Android share image and text on Twitter

Tags: android

I want to share text and image from url on twitter. I have a button with twitter icon. If user click the button, I want to open twitter app. if phone doesn't have twitter app it should go twitter on browser. How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
try {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
          Uri.parse("twitter://user?screen_name=[user_name]"));
    startActivity(intent);
} catch (Exception e) {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
          Uri.parse("https://twitter.com/#!/[user_name]")));
}
```